# How to access indicated items in a tuple rather than all of them

Tags: python, tuples

So I'm trying to write code to change an entered integer number into a month.  The goal is to take an entered argument and convert it to a date.  Code below.

```
def date(month, day, year):
    mon = ("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", 
     "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")
    for i in range(len(mon)):
        print(mon[i]+" "+str(day)+", "+str(year))
```

With this code I can get it to print all the dates from January to December in the correct format but I don't know what to change

```
for i in range(len(mon)):
```

to in order to select only the month entered in the argument.

EX: When entered into the console as `date(6,17,2016)` it should print `June 17, 2016`.

Comment: `print(month[i-1]+" "+str(day)+", "+str(year))` or have a blank element in the beginning of tuple such as `mon = ("", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")` and then use `print(month[i])`.

Comment: shahkalpesh's suggestion brings up IndexError: tuple index out of range.   Coldspeed, I wish I didn't have to.

Comment: I updated my comment. What example causes the `IndexError`?

Comment: changing month[i] to month[i+1] but that makes sense with the +1.  the problem here is that I don't know how to use an argument in the console to select only one month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove that for loop and access the `mon` tuple by index, for example:

```
def date(month, day, year):
    mon = ("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", 
     "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")
    print('{} {}, {}'.format(mon[month-1], day, year))
```

Since tuples indexing start from `0` you can access each month by using `month-1` for example

**1 - 1 = 0** for `January` since `mon[0]` is `January`.

Comment: I swear I tried this exact thing 20 minutes ago and it didn't work.  And now it works. Obviously user error on my part.   Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help :-)